# python3 -m pip: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'

Tags: python, pip, urllib3

I am running `python3`:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
```

I was going to update local `pip` packages and for that I first checked which were outdated:

```
python3 -m pip list --outdated
```

This produced a warning message for each specific package (they are all the same so I am showing only a sample):

```
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1015: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1015: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1015: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1015: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1015: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'pypi.org'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

At the end this produced a list of packages, but I want to understand why `pip` is showing this behavior.

I checked the [recommended page](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) in the warning, but it does not provide any useful information for my case, as it is focused on programming use cases which use the `urllib3` and `requests` packages directly.

There are suggestions to ignore this warning (with all the perils it entails) with a command-line argument passed to `pip`.

I have no idea why this warning started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the problem exactly, but it got fixed after upgrading `pip`.

The old version:

```
python3 -m pip debug --verbose
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I then upgraded `pip` as such:

```
python3 -m pip install -U  pip --upgrade

python3 -m pip --version

pip 23.2.1 from /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

After upgrading `pip`, the warnings disappeared.